# Regular Expression | Catch domain from url with subdomain

Tags: php, regex, subdomain

Im using a regex on PHP to convert an url to a domain like below

```
function getDomainFromUrl($url) {
    $pieces = parse_url($url);
    $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
    if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i',$domain, $regs)) {
        return $regs['domain'];
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now I want to get domain with its subdomain. What should I do on my regex?

Now:

```
http://subdomain.example.com -> returns to example.com
```

Expected:

```
subomain.example.com
```

Last but most important part for me:
if url has `www.` subdomain should be removed. I don't want to get `www.`

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
function getDomainFromUrl($url) {
    if (!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
        $url = 'http://' . $url;
    }
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    return preg_replace('/^www\./', '', $host);
}
```

Comment: If url has only subdomain. It is return null. Please help me :)

Comment: @hakkikonu, I've added a quick dirty check for a scheme part. Now it works for `http` and `https`. But, I think, that it may be possible to accomplish this in some other way.

Comment: @hakkikonu, I've updated the function once more time. It looks like a `filter_var` function is much better solution here. It works nice with other schemes, not only `http` and `https`.

Answer (score 1):

```
print get_domain("http://subomain.example.com"); // outputs 'example.com'

function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: If url has only subdomain. It is return null. Please help me :)

Comment: Also I want to get  subdomain.example.com not example.com

Comment: if you use domains with tld more than 6 chars. this fails. and if you grow up {2,6} as {2,10]} this works even worser. example domain is www.test.istanbul